# How do I prove $N(aHa^{-1})= aN(H)a^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory

Here $a \in G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. I have no idea where to begin with this. Please help?

Comment: what does N mean ?

Comment: Normalizer, I thought

Comment: If it is normalizer ignore my answer. If it is just a normal subgroup the my answer is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}k\in N_G(aHa^{-1})\Longleftrightarrow & kaHa^{-1}=aHa^{-1}k\\
\Longleftrightarrow &
a^{-1}kaH\underbrace{a^{-1}k^{-1}a}_{(a^{-1}ka)^{-1}}=H\\
\Longleftrightarrow &a^{-1}ka\in N_G(H)\\
\Longleftrightarrow &k\in aN_G(H)a^{-1}=N_G(H)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Conjugation is an automorphism of $G$ and hence acts on everything that is "reasonably" defined about $G$. Specifically, taking the normalizer commutes with automorphisms of $G$ (or with isomorphisms between different groups) because *normalizer* is indeed  defined  "reasonably", i.e., merely in terms of the general properties of the group operation and logic.